# trying to include a non existing file causes ng-include to go into infinite loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in section.elements" ng-include="'/templ_url/'+element.name+'.html'"></div>
```

Where `element.name` is a string that matches a file inside /templ_url. If the file exists it works! However, if the file does not exist instead of not including anything or trowing some sort of error it goes into an infinite loop that eventually crashes the browser.

Is there a way to prevent this, as I said maybe not include anything. Or if there is a way to check if the file exists before ng-include

FYI:
The issue is not whether section.elements == "" but whether the content of section.elements reference a file that exist in the /templ_url directory

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in section.elements | filter: { name: '' }" 
   ng-include="'/templ_url/'+ element.name +'.html'">
</div>
```

It might filter out empty "name" attributes from the loop.

Comment: Read the question the issue is not whether section.elements == "" but whether the content of section.elements reference a file that exist in the /templ_url directory

Comment: use $http to get you files content, then ng-repeat with ng-bind-html attribute.

Comment: Can you provide example in answer if it works I will give it to you